# Libreoffice C++ extension shortcut

Tags: c++, keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice

It is possible to write extensions for Libreoffice in C++. I managed to add a menu item and a toolbar item from my extension, by mainly following [this guide](https://niocs.github.io/LOBook/extensions/part6.html).

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut (aka accelerator in libreoffice terminology) to the menu item that triggers some action in my extension.

All working examples I found online were for scripts (python or basic), but not for complied C++. The best attempt I found is [this question](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/112656/set-keyboard-shortcuts-for-extensions/), but apparently they didn't succeed. There's a [wiki page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Accelerators_Configuration#Example) on the subject, but it's not very useful, despite claiming "now we can define and install shortcuts for our extensions easily."

For sample code, please consider this repository: `https://github.com/niocs/ProtocolHandlerExtension.git`

Comment: Generally, as part of your extension, you write a *Keypress Handler*, that test for needed keepresses and if found, you invoke the needed action and return 1 indicating that any of the further key handlers in other portions of LO need not respond to that keypress. You add the accelerator to your menu item through the main-window accelerator table (it just adds the key-combo to the menu item), but all invoking of what it does is done in your keypress handler. There are a number of Gtk examples of how to do this. Search "gtk keypress handler".

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi, thanks for your input. To register a GTK evenet listener, I would need a reference to the GTK window object, which I'm not sure how to acquire. I searched the LO extension API docs and haven't found a single reference to anything GTK related. Also, if I understand correctly, LO uses some mixture of Qt/GTK depending on the environment, which makes doubt that this is a viable approach.